# GCP: Error connecting to cloudsql mysql from app engine standard: ENOENT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a nodejs app which uses mysql. I have taken following steps to deploy the setup on GCP.

- Created project: P-1
- Enabled Cloud SQL Admin Api
- Created MySQL instance: M-1
- Enabled Public IP for MySQl instance
- Added Cloud SQL Client Role for App Engine Service Account

**Config**

```
socketPath: /cloudsql/P-1:<zone>:M-1
user: <user>
password: <pwd>
database: <db>
```

When I try to deploy the app it fails with ENOENT error:

`Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/P-1:<zone>:M-1`

What am I doing wrong here? Kindly help!!

I have already tried all the previous Stackoverflow posts and GCP documentation.

**UPDATE 1**

app.yaml has:

```
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: "<CONNECTION_NAME>"
```

- I can also connect to MySQL using Cloud Shell.
- App and SQL instance are in the same region.
- I have deleted and recreated the database instance.

**Update 2**

The exception is :

```
Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/P-1:<zone>:M-1
    at Object.createConnection
```

Comment: please update the question with your application's connection code. The node.js code will be very beneficial for attempting to debug or reproduce.

Comment: also this previous thread might have some useful suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41971154/enoent-when-connecting-to-google-cloud-sql-from-app-engine